# Using map and zip to determine if sequential items in list have a difference equal to 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, lambda, zip

Python beginner here, looking for some guidance and insight. I have the following code that works in python:

```
z=0
y=0
valid=[]
test = [1,2,1,3,4,4,5,2,6,7]

for i, j in zip(test, test[1:]):
    if (j - i) == 1:
        z += 1
    valid.append(i)
    valid.append(j)
else:
    y += 1

print("There are " + str(len(test)) + " entries with " + str(z) + " sequential events and " + str(y) + " non-sequentual events")

print(list(valid))
```

This gives me the output I hope for:

```
There are 10 entries with 4 sequential events and 5 non-sequentual events
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

I would prefer to be more Pythonic and I am trying to recreate this with map and zip:

```
map(diff_val(help_here_pls), zip(test, test[1:]))
```

I know that maps follows "map(function, iterable)". How can I get my map output to match my preferred list of

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

using a function (the help_here_pls").

I know that:

- zip creates a tuple'd list
- map take a function and iterable (from my zip in this case)

Do I pass a tuple via the function in map? Can a lambda handle this, or do I need to define a separate function? Even if I can do that, do I have to unpack the tuple?
    (i ,j) = [passed tuple]

Thanks in advance for any guidance you can provide! reading / references welcomed!

Comment: A list comprehension would be best here: `[n for tup in zip(test, test[1:]) for n in tup if tup[1]-tup[0] == 1]`.  Although I would prefer results that showed that I had pairs of numbers so I would do `[(i,j) for (i,j) in zip(test, test[1:]) if j-i == 1]` giving `[(1, 2), (3, 4), (4, 5), (6, 7)]`

Comment: when I run your example I get `There are 10 entries with 4 sequential events and 1 non-sequentual events
[1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 2, 2, 6, 6, 7]`

Comment: @jacoblaw I'm running on C9.io using python 3.4.3. Not sure what's happening there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A list comprehension is the pythonic choice here.  I changed the result to give a list of tuples because the flattened list obscured that there is a relationship between each pair of items.

```
test = [1,2,1,3,4,4,5,2,6,7]
valid = [(i,j) for (i,j) in zip(test, test[1:]) if j-i == 1]
s = "There are {} entries with {} sequential events and {} non-sequentual events"
print(s.format(len(test), len(valid), len(test)-1-len(valid)))
print(valid)
```

Output:

```
There are 10 entries with 4 sequential events and 5 non-sequentual events
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (4, 5), (6, 7)]
```

Here's another way using [`more_itertools`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```
from operator import sub # function for subtraction
from more_itertools import flatten, pairwise

list(flatten(t for t in pairwise(test) if sub(*t)==-1))
```

gives

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: Thanks @steven! The list comprehension is an elegant way to handle this. Perhaps it is my non-Pythonic way of describing things, but the flattened list is actually the result I would need for further processing. I'm still trying to grasp the use of for loops with multiple index/iterators. using `valid = [n for tup in zip(test, test[1:]) for n in tup if tup[1]-tup[0] == 1]]` did the trick

Comment: Looking at this more, I'm thinking there is a way to parse the list of integers similarly, without the initial `zip(a,a[1:])` I'll be back...

Comment: The thing I don't like about the flattened list is that  it's hard to tell from glancing at `[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7]` that 1 and 2 relate while 2 and 3 do not.  If you do use the flattened list then your number of sequential events is `len(valid)/2)`.

Comment: Ahhh... That printed line is my "how do I debug / validate this idea". This parsing will eventually be used to determine datetime object's sequentiality (is that a word?) and toss objects that aren't sequential. I figured if I could figure it out with integers first, I can apply the logic elsewhere.

Comment: @lucholland:  I added an example that uses `pairwise` and `flatten` from the [`more_itertools`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) module that helps you do away with `zip` and gets rid of the nested for-loop.  (`more_itertools` is an external module that you would need to install.)

Comment: the more_itertools code is great, but a limitation I also have is "vanilla" python - no external modules outside of the base python libraries. Thanks for your help with this!